# Pointer in deleting a node in single linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

In place of `*head_ref = temp->next;`, why can't I assign it as `*head_ref = *head_ref->next`?

Why should I use `temp`? Aren't they pointing to the same place?

```
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void deleteNode(Node** head_ref, int key){
    Node* temp = *head_ref;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    
    if(temp!=NULL && temp->data==key){
        *head_ref = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        return;
    }
    
    else{
        while(temp!=NULL && *head_ref->data!=key){
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That shouldn't even compile: `*head_ref->data` ==> `(*head_ref)->data`

Comment: [Edit] ans show a [mcve]

Comment: @mch May I ask the reason for not compiling?

Comment: `*head_ref->next` is `*(head_ref->next)`, not `(*head_ref)->next`.

Comment: What is the difference between {temp = (*head_ref)->next} and {temp = temp->next}?

Comment: `temp` and `*head_ref` have the same value (to begin with), but they are not the same thing. If you have `int* ip = new int(1); int temp = *ip;`, then `*ip = 2;` and `temp = 2;` will do completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile, `*head_ref->data` should be `(*head_ref)->data`.

The reason why you should use `temp` is that you want to modify `*head_ref` only if the element you want to delete is the head element. If you delete any other element of the list, the head pointer must stay the same.

But your code is wrong anyway. You're doing things in the wrong order. You must first find the element you want to delete, and then handle the deletion.

Your code handles the deletion first and then finds the element to delete which is absurd.

You want this:

```
void deleteNode(Node** head_ref, int key) {
  Node* current = *head_ref;
  Node* previous = NULL;

  // find element to delete
  while (current && current->data != key)
  {
    previous = current;
    current = current->next;
  }

  // if current is NULL here then the element has not been found

  if (current != NULL)
  {
    // element found, 
    // current points to element found
    // previous points to previous element or NULL if current is head

    if (previous == NULL)
    {
      // deleting head element -> we need to update head_ref
      *head_ref = current->next;
    }
    else
    {
      // deleting any other element -> update next pointer of previous element
      previous->next = current->next;
    }

    delete current;
  }
}
```

That being said, this is rather C code than C++ code. You should use standard containers rather than making your own, or at least use C++ idioms such as constructors.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. May I ask one more question? What is the difference between {temp = (temp = *head_ref)->next;} and {temp = temp->next}? Isn't temp and *head_ref pointing to the same thing?

Comment: Assuming `*head_ref` and `temp` are equal (that is pointing to the same thing), `temp = (*head_ref)->next` and `temp = temp->next` do the same thing. But if the statement is executed more than once because it is in a loop, then it's very different.